# Performance loss with CopyResource() and then Map()/Unmap()

Tags: windows, performance, directx, directx-11, frame-rate

The problem is that if you do not use these methods, then the FPS differs by about 2 times in a big way. For example, I had about 5000 fps in a 3d scene. And it became about 2500. I know that the problem is that the application is waiting for the copy to wait. But it's only 4 bytes... If you use the D3D11_MAP_FLAG_DO_NOT_WAIT flag, Map() will always return DXGI_ERROR_WAS_STILL_DRAWING. What can be done so that I can use this method without losing fps? Here is my code:

**Init**

```cpp
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC outputDesc;
    outputDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    outputDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(float);
    outputDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS;
    outputDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    outputDesc.StructureByteStride = sizeof(float);
    outputDesc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_BUFFER_STRUCTURED;
    FOG_TRACE(mDevice->CreateBuffer(&outputDesc, nullptr, &outputBuffer));

    outputDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
    outputDesc.BindFlags = 0;
    outputDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
    FOG_TRACE(mDevice->CreateBuffer(&outputDesc, nullptr, &outputResultBuffer));

    D3D11_UNORDERED_ACCESS_VIEW_DESC uavDesc{};
    uavDesc.Buffer.FirstElement = 0;
    uavDesc.Buffer.Flags = D3D11_BUFFER_UAV_FLAG_APPEND;
    uavDesc.Buffer.NumElements = 1;
    uavDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;
    uavDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_UAV_DIMENSION_BUFFER;

    FOG_TRACE(mDevice->CreateUnorderedAccessView(outputBuffer, &uavDesc, &unorderedAccessView));
```

**Update**

```cpp
    const UINT offset = 0;
    mDeviceContext->OMSetRenderTargetsAndUnorderedAccessViews(1, &mRenderTargetView, mDepthStencilView, 1, 1, &unorderedAccessView, &offset);
    mDeviceContext->ClearDepthStencilView(mDepthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);


    ObjectManager::Draw();


    mDeviceContext->CopyResource(outputResultBuffer, outputBuffer);

    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedBuffer;
    HRESULT hr;
    FOG_TRACE(hr = mDeviceContext->Map(outputResultBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0/*D3D11_MAP_FLAG_DO_NOT_WAIT*/, &mappedBuffer));

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        float* copy = (float*)(mappedBuffer.pData);
        OutputDebugString(String::ToStr(*copy) + L"\n");
    }

    mDeviceContext->Unmap(outputResultBuffer, 0);

    const UINT var[4]{};
    mDeviceContext->ClearUnorderedAccessViewUint(unorderedAccessView, var);
```

I've already profiled and checked everything possible, the problem is exactly in pending. I would be very grateful if someone could explain everything in detail :)

Comment: Avoid OutputDebugString, it's an old piece of horribly slow crap. Unmap only if Map succeeded. Other than that, exchanging data between GPU and CPU is notoriously costly, so, maybe painful in main loop.

Comment: Look at the solution please. I need an estimate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved very simply but for a long time! I just didn't make copy calls until I had read past data. Here is a small crutch:

```cpp
    static bool isWait = false;

    if (!isWait)
    {
        mDeviceContext->CopyResource(outputResultBuffer, outputBuffer);
    }

    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedBuffer;
    HRESULT hr;

    FOG_TRACE(hr = mDeviceContext->Map(outputResultBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, D3D11_MAP_FLAG_DO_NOT_WAIT, &mappedBuffer));


    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        float* copy = (float*)(mappedBuffer.pData);
        OutputDebugString(String::ToStr(*copy) + L"\n");
        mDeviceContext->Unmap(outputResultBuffer, 0);

        const UINT var[4]{};
        mDeviceContext->ClearUnorderedAccessViewUint(unorderedAccessView, var);

        isWait = false;
    }
    else
    {
        isWait = true;
    }
```